# How can I see each Cordova's project version?

Tags: cordova

Recently, I installed the latest version of Cordova (5.3.3) on a former coworker's mac. But there's already some projects created with Cordova.

Is it possible to see each project's Cordova version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

open a terminal (mac/linux) or a CMD (windows) and go to your project folder, then enter this command

```
cordova platform list
```

You'll see the version of the platform installed for that project

Comment: Thank you. Since this is new to me, I am very confused.